# XSLT Data Merge

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, data-manipulation

I have a very basic knowledge of XSLT and I am currently trying to achieve something which I am still trying to figure out if its possible.

Can be XSLT 1.0 or 2.0

Basically this is the structure of my XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Root>
    <DataPage>
        <Record>
            <TEMP>xxx</TEMP>
            <DEBITNO>6250281</DEBITNO>
            <DOSSIERNUMMERINT>2012365</DOSSIERNUMMERINT>
            <ID>0123456789Z60</ID>
            <DATE>31/01/2013</DATE>
            <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
            <DESC>Test Item 1</DESC>
            <AMOUNT>           38170.0000000</AMOUNT>
            <HEAD>123</HEAD>
        </Record>
    </DataPage>
    <DataPage>
        <Record>
            <TEMP>xxx</TEMP>
            <DEBITNO>6250281</DEBITNO>
            <DOSSIERNUMMERINT>2012365</DOSSIERNUMMERINT>
            <ID>0123456789Z70</ID>
            <DATE>22/02/2013</DATE>
            <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
            <DESC>Test Item 2</DESC>
            <AMOUNT>           14410.0000000</AMOUNT>
            <HEAD>123</HEAD>
        </Record>
    </DataPage>
    <DataPage>
        <Record>
            <TEMP>xxx</TEMP>
            <DEBITNO>3849322</DEBITNO>
            <DOSSIERNUMMERINT>20132394</DOSSIERNUMMERINT>
            <ID>34958701223Z20</ID>
            <DATE>06/01/2013</DATE>
            <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
            <DESC>Test Item 1</DESC>
            <AMOUNT>           33811.0000000</AMOUNT>
            <HEAD>567</HEAD>
        </Record>
    </DataPage>
</Root>
```

I would like this the output the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Root>
    <DataPage>
        <Record>
            <TEMP>xxx</TEMP>
            <DEBITNO>6250281</DEBITNO>
            <DOSSIERNUMMERINT>2012365</DOSSIERNUMMERINT>
            <Line>
                <ID>0123456789Z60</ID>
                <DATE>31/01/2013</DATE>
                <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
                <DESC>Test Item 1</DESC>
                <AMOUNT>           38170.0000000</AMOUNT>
            </Line>
            <Line>
                <ID>0123456789Z70</ID>
                <DATE>22/02/2013</DATE>
                <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
                <DESC>Test Item 2</DESC>
                <AMOUNT>           14410.0000000</AMOUNT>
            </Line>
            <HEAD>123</HEAD>
        </Record>
    </DataPage>
    <DataPage>
        <Record>
            <TEMP>xxx</TEMP>
            <DEBITNO>3849322</DEBITNO>
            <DOSSIERNUMMERINT>20132394</DOSSIERNUMMERINT>
            <Line>
                <ID>34958701223Z20</ID>
                <DATE>06/01/2013</DATE>
                <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
                <DESC>Test Item 1</DESC>
                <AMOUNT>           33811.0000000</AMOUNT>
            </Line>
            <HEAD>567</HEAD>
        </Record>
    </DataPage>
</Root>
```

So the logic would be to merge all records with the same DEBITNO.

The rules for the merge is everything other than ID, Date, Year, DESC and AMOUNT can be taken from the 1st appearance

ID, Date, Year, DESC and AMOUNT needs to be placed into a  tag, so if there are 2 records with the same DEBITNO there will be 2 line items, if there are 5 records with the same DEBITNO the resulting record will have 5 line items.

I hope that makes sense.

Is something like this possible?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all due respect to Mr. Kay's decision about do not provide solutions, this one in xslt 1.0 solves your particular case and also is a solution for more general cases where you can have a *`multiroot`* with several `root` elements and local grouping is required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name ="k1" match="DataPage[
    not(preceding-sibling::DataPage/Record/DEBITNO = Record/DEBITNO)
    ]"
    use="generate-id()"/>

  <xsl:key name="k2" match="DataPage[
    preceding-sibling::DataPage/Record/DEBITNO = Record/DEBITNO]"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::DataPage[
      Record/DEBITNO= current()/Record/DEBITNO
    ][last()])" />
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="DataPage"/>
  <xsl:template match="DataPage[key('k1',generate-id())]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Record>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/TEMP
          |Record/DEBITNO
          |Record/DOSSIERNUMMERINT"/>
        <xsl:for-each select=".|key('k2',generate-id())">
          <Line>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/ID
              |Record/DATE
              |Record/YEAR
              |Record/DESC
              |Record/AMOUNT"/>
          </Line>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/HEAD"/>
      </Record>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Caveat: It seems some XSLT processors does not support `current()` function use in `k2` definition

If you want a more simple solution just for your case (doesn't support local grouping) you can use this Muenchian like method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name ="k" match="DataPage"
    use="Record/DEBITNO"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="DataPage"/>
  <xsl:template match="DataPage[ 
    generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', Record/DEBITNO)[1])
  ]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Record>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/TEMP
          |Record/DEBITNO
          |Record/DOSSIERNUMMERINT"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('k', Record/DEBITNO)">
          <Line>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/ID
              |Record/DATE
              |Record/YEAR
              |Record/DESC
              |Record/AMOUNT"/>
          </Line>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/HEAD"/>
      </Record>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In xslt 1.0 this a well known method, the [Muenchian method](https://www.google.pt/search?q=xslt+Muenchian+Method).

I wrote myself a paper about it and some minor variations. You can also find it [here](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~prodei/DSIE08/papers/43.pdf)

Comment: Hi All

I have not forgotten about this thread or just taken the answers and left, I have just been extremely busy and still intend on testing and learning from both replies.

I will post back as soon as my schedule allows for some testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard grouping problem. In XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="DataPage/Record" group-by="DEBITNO">
  <DataPage>
    <Record>
     <xsl:copy-of select="TEMP, DEBITNO, DOSSIERNUMMERINT"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
       <Line>
         <xsl:copy-of select="ID, YEAR, DATE, DESC, AMOUNT"/>
       </
     </
   </
  </
 </
</
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Forgive me as like I said I have limited knowledge of XSLT.

The concept makes sense to me, but putting this into a practice not so much, I assume this is to give me an idea and not an actual functional XSLT, I am going through it to try and get this worked out.

Thanks!

Comment: Correct, my normal style is not to write programs for people, but to point them in the right direction and help them up the learning curve. I would strongly recommend reading about xsl:for-each-group in a book such as my own before you try to use it in production code.